# Receive messsages off all sockets without looping through all sockets

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener, tcpsocket

I am writing a messaging application using C# and unity for my a level project, it is using a tcp client-sever model. I have created a list of sockets that can receive messages, but I have to specify the socket to receive the message from, this is fine for testing when i only have 1 client, but I need to be able to handle more connections, and looping through each socket to try and receive a message from it seems very inefficient and slow.

My question is: how can I receive messages from multiple clients without using the aforementioned method?

I'm going to post the specific sections, and then the entire code so you understand what I'm doing.

This is the thread that deals with receiving the data form the socket

```
    public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[155];
            ///////// I need to specify the socket to receive from////////
            int k = counter.numbers1[counter.i2].Receive(b);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            string k1 = "";

            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < k; i3++)
                k1 = k1 + Convert.ToChar(b[i3]);

            Console.WriteLine(k1);

            string sender_endpoint = k1.Substring(0, 21); ;
            string receiver_endpoint = k1.Substring(22, 21);
            string message = k1.Substring(44, 100);
            string msgtype = k1.Substring(145, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(k1.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(sender_endpoint);
            Console.WriteLine(receiver_endpoint);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine(msgtype);

            if (msgtype == "0") //message
            {
                Console.WriteLine("000");
            }
            else if (msgtype == "1") //command
            {
                Console.WriteLine("111");
            }
        }
    }
```

The full server code is:

```
namespace server
{
    static class counter
    {
        public static int i2 = 0;//main listener
        public static int i4 = 0;//port number
        public static List<TcpListener> numbers = new List<TcpListener>();//listeners
        public static List<Socket> numbers1 = new List<Socket>();//sockets
    }

    class server_code
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string xyz123 = "x";
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread3));
            Thread test_thread = new Thread(() => Test_Thread (xyz123));
            thread3.Start();
        }

        public static void Thread1()
        {
            //message reactions
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[155];
                int k = counter.numbers1[counter.i2].Receive(b);
                string k1 = "";

                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < k; i3++)
                    k1 = k1 + Convert.ToChar(b[i3]);

                Console.WriteLine(k1);

                string sender_endpoint = k1.Substring(0, 21); ;
                string receiver_endpoint = k1.Substring(22, 21);
                string message = k1.Substring(44, 100);
                string msgtype = k1.Substring(145, 1);
                Console.WriteLine(k1.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(sender_endpoint);
                Console.WriteLine(receiver_endpoint);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Console.WriteLine(msgtype);

                if (msgtype == "0") //message
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("000");
                }
                else if (msgtype == "1") //command
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("111");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Thread2()
        {
            //client message receiver
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString());

                    counter.numbers.Add(null); 
                    counter.numbers1.Add(null);

                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Socket xyz1 = counter.numbers[counter.i2].AcceptSocket();

                    counter.numbers1[counter.i2] = xyz1;
                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    counter.numbers1[counter.i2].Send(asen.GetBytes(counter.numbers1[counter.i2].RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + counter.numbers1[counter.i2].RemoteEndPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine("connecting to " + counter.numbers[counter.i2].LocalEndpoint);
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
                    thread1.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Thread3()
        {
            //new clients acception
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
                        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString());
                        TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8080);
                        myList.Start();
                        Console.WriteLine("The local endpoint is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);

                        Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();//////////////////////////////////////////////
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
                        Console.WriteLine("connecting to " + myList.LocalEndpoint);
                        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                        counter.i2 = counter.i2 + i;
                        int portno = 8000;
                        s.Send(asen.GetBytes(portno.ToString()));

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        myList.Stop();
                        s.Close();
                        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));

                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        counter.numbers.Add(null);

                        TcpListener xyz = new TcpListener(ipAd, portno);

                        counter.numbers[counter.i2] = xyz;
                        //Console.WriteLine(counter.i4);//current portno

                        counter.numbers[counter.i2].Start();
                        Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + counter.numbers[counter.i2].LocalEndpoint);
                        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        thread2.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The full client code is:

```
public class cc : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public InputField NameField;
    private string x;
    private string y = "";
    //private int z = 0;

    static class ipadressnumber{
        public static string ipadressno = "192.168.1.250";
    }

    public void Start(){
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

            tcpclnt.Connect(ipadressnumber.ipadressno,8080);
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++){
                y = y + Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
            }
            //Debug.Log(y);
            tcpclnt.Close();
    }

    public void OnSubmit() 
    {
        x =  NameField.text;
        //Debug.Log(x);

        try 
        {
            System.Net.IPAddress ipad = IPAddress.Parse(ipadressnumber.ipadressno);
            IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipad,8888);
            //TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipLocalEndPoint);
            TcpClient tcpclnt1 = new TcpClient();
            //Debug.Log(y);
            tcpclnt1.Connect(ipadressnumber.ipadressno,int.Parse(y));
            Stream stm = tcpclnt1.GetStream();

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);
            string lclep = "";

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++) 
            {
                lclep = lclep + Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
            }

            String str=x;
            ////////////format of message:(sender endpoint, recipient endpoint, message, message type, check sum/digit)
            string message = "";
            int strlen = 21;
            int msglen = 100;
            string msgtype = "0";// 0 = message, 1 = command
            lclep = Convert.ToString(lclep);
            Debug.Log (lclep);

            while (strlen > lclep.Length)
            {
                Debug.Log('1');
                lclep = lclep + "#";
            }

            string rmtep = "000.00.00.000:8000";

            while (strlen > rmtep.Length)
            {
                Debug.Log ('2');
                rmtep = rmtep + "#";
            }

            while (msglen > x.Length)
            {
                Debug.Log ('3');
                x = x + "#";
            }           

            message = message + lclep + ':' + rmtep + ':' + x + ':' + msgtype + ':';
            Debug.Log(message);

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = new byte[155];
            ba=asen.GetBytes(message);

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            tcpclnt1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
192.168.1.250
The local End point is  :192.168.1.250:8080
Connection accepted from 192.168.1.250:54024
connecting to 192.168.1.250:8080

The local End point is  :192.168.1.250:8000
192.168.1.250
The local End point is  :192.168.1.250:8080

Connection accepted from 192.168.1.250:54055
connecting to 192.168.1.250:8000
192.168.1.250:54055##:000.00.00.000:8000###:message test 1 for stackoverflow####################################################################:0:
147
192.168.1.250:54055##
000.00.00.000:8000###
message test 1 for stackoverflow####################################################################
0
000
```

As you can see I don't get any errors so all I need is a way to receive messages form multiple clients.

Comment: Just a future note, we don't need to see you using namespace declarations,

Comment: okay, thanks, didn't know exactly what people would need to solve the problem, didnt want to risk it. won't include it in future.

Comment: _"looping through each socket to try and recieve a message from it"_ -- that's called "polling", and you should never do that. As you say, it's inefficient. That said, if you'd actually done some significant research, you would have found various techniques to read from sockets specifically when they have data toread, most of the "asynchronous" variety, though one option is in fact to dedicate a single thread to each socket...

Comment: ... (only acceptable when you are dealing with a very small number of sockets...dozens at most). To educate you on the topic you should instead just find references for would be far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's **receive** - not "recieve" ....

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to name some of these techniques so I can find out if I can implement them? And I apologise for my insignificant research, I couldnt find anything after a week so I came here

Answer (score 0):

I will give a possible solution to the problem I understood: How do I listen for multiple sockets and process their messages simultaneously?

You could start one thread for each socket you need, this Reader Thread would read the entire message and send to a thread safe list in another thread that I will call the Processing Thread. This last thread will apply your business logic to the data read by your socket, generate a response and send it to another thread: The Writer Thread.

Socker -> Readers -> Processor -> Writer

Don't start your threads like in your Thread3 and Thread2 methods, this demands too much CPU and can slow down your application. Create the threads beforehand and start then in the appropriate order.

Comment: Surely that could be just as inefficient and very demanding on the processor? Having hundreds of threads running at once? And sorry about not having a mcve

Comment: How many clients does your program expects to listen to? I don't know when the number of threads starts to become a problem to the CPU, but I think that a pool of threads could solve that. The problem with the pool is how to manage the assignment of multiple socket instances to a thread pool.

Comment: For my project, I would need up to a hundred, but I'm going to continue developing it after a levels so I can publish it, ideally I would like to be able to handle a few thousand